Jump to the end of " " (double quotes), then change to insert mode using vim
<div class="hidden md:block">
    // other codes here
</div>

If ci" delete everything inside double quotes, is there a way to retain everything inside the double quotes and append to the end of it? From the example code above, let say I want to retain the hidden md:block class and then add another class after it.
I tried A which jumps to the end of the entire line in insert mode. I also tried ci" but it deletes everything inside.

Any of 2f"i or $F"i or even ci"<C-R>" will work. See :help motion.txt for ways to move the cursor.

Another one: vi"<Esc>a.

You can also try a plugin like flash.nvim, which can help you get around easily. However, if you are new to Vim, I recommend learning the fundamentals like others here have pointed out.

As everything in Vim, there are many ways to do achieve your goal. From the comments:

2f"i moves the cursor to the second " and enters insert mode.

$F"i moves the cursor to the end of the line, then to the first " to the left, and enters insert mode.

ci"<C-R>" cuts the content of the current/next quote text object and inserts it again, effectively leaving you in insert mode just before the closing ".

vi"<Esc>a visually selects the content of the current/next quote text object, then leaves visual mode, leaving the cursor on the last character covered by the text object, and finally enters insert mode after the cursor.


And there are others:

fka moves the cursor to the k of block and enters insert mode after it.

$hi or $<left>i moves the cursor to the end of the line, then one character to the left, and enters insert mode.

A<left><left> enters insert mode at the end of the line and moves the cursor.

And probably others…


Some of those could be called "low-level" and others "high-level".
The low-level ones are highly contextual by nature so the amount of effort required is not deterministic, but they tend to be very concise and easy to compose.
The high-level ones don't depend much about the current context, which makes them relatively "universal". The upside is that they can be used in lots of scenarios with the same amount effort. The downside is that they can be a handful.
And then you have even higher-level ways provided by plugins.
The high-level ones are smarter, in a way, and using them fluently is certainly a sign that you "grok Vim", at least to a certain extent. But something like A<left><left> is a hell of a lot quicker and more intuitive, if applicable.
Learning Vim essentially consists in expanding one's vocabulary and building an intuition for which method to use when.
:help navigation will blow your mind.
Speaking of "high-level", here is a quick and dirty snippet that gives you a bunch of visual, operator-pending, and normal mode commands for moving the cursor to the end (lowercase) or start (UPPERCASE) of a text object:
for ch in [ "]", "[", "(", ")", "b", "{", "}", "B", "<", ">", "t", "'", "`", '"' ]
    " visual mode and operator-pending mode
    execute "xnoremap gi" . ch . " i" . ch . "<Esc>"
    execute "onoremap gi" . ch . " :normal vgi" . ch . "<CR>"
    execute "xnoremap ga" . ch . " a" . ch . "<Esc>"
    execute "onoremap ga" . ch . " :normal vga" . ch . "<CR>"
    execute "xnoremap gI" . ch . " i" . ch . "o<Esc>"
    execute "onoremap gI" . ch . " :normal vgi" . ch . "<CR>"
    execute "xnoremap gA" . ch . " a" . ch . "o<Esc>"
    execute "onoremap gA" . ch . " :normal vga" . ch . "<CR>"

    " normal mode
    execute "nmap ggi" . ch . " vgi" . ch . "<Esc>"
    execute "nmap gga" . ch . " vga" . ch . "<Esc>"
    execute "nmap ggI" . ch . " vgI" . ch . "<Esc>"
    execute "nmap ggA" . ch . " vgA" . ch . "<Esc>"
endfor

Which would make your use case only a matter of ggi"a or gga"i. Prefixes are arbitrary and possibly misguided, change to taste.
